# MYSQL: Selecting value in column where column name is defined on a seperate table

Tags: mysql, dynamic

I'm not sure this is possible with just SQL...any help will be appreciated:

I'm trying to retrieve a value in a column in table B (tblProduct).
The column name is actually defined in reference table A (tblConfig_Group).

So, essentially, I'm **given the tblConfig_Group.groupCode and tblProduct.VCI** values

I need to **retrieve the value in the appropriate column in tblProduct set in dbColumnUK**.

**tblConfig_Group:**

```
+----+-----------+-------------+
| id | groupCode | dbColumnUK  |
+----+-----------+-------------+
| 01 | A         | WindowGBP_A |
| 02 | B         | WindowGBP_B |
| 03 | C         | WindowGBP_C |
| 04 | D         | WindowGBP_D |
+----+-----------+-------------+
```

**tblProduct:**

```
+----+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| id | VCI     | WindowGBP_A | WindowGBP_B | WindowGBP_C | WindowGBP_D |
+----+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 01 | vci1    | 1           | 11          | 21          | 31          |
| 02 | vci2    | 2           | 12          | 22          | 32          |
| 03 | vci3    | 3           | 13          | 23          | 33          |
| 04 | vci4    | 4           | 14          | 24          | 34          |
+----+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Hi Jocelyn 
The sql isn't anywhere near a solution. I need to understand if selecting a column by variable is even technically possible first...

`
      SELECT cg.dbColumnUK, p.VCI, p.`dbColumnUK`  
      FROM  tblConfig_Group cg, tblProduct p 
      WHERE  cg.groupCode = B
      AND cg.dbColumnUK = p.dbColumnUK   
    AND p.VCI = 'vci2';
`

Comment: yeah I think I can do this.

Comment: Normalise your design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT CASE g.dbColumnUK 
          WHEN 'WindowGBP_A' THEN p.WindowGBP_A
          WHEN 'WindowGBP_B' THEN p.WindowGBP_B
          WHEN 'WindowGBP_C' THEN p.WindowGBP_C
          WHEN 'WindowGBP_D' THEN p.WindowGBP_D
       END AS col
FROM tblProduct AS p
CROSS JOIN (SELECT dbColumnUK FROM tblConfig_Group WHERE groupCode='A') AS g 
WHERE VCI = 'vci2'
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62407c/1)

Comment: Thanks Giorgos, this is a nice solution but i'm afraid the list of groups will increase by the end users so unable to have this hard coded.

Comment: @nads In this case I would suggest to consider redesigning the schema of your database.

Comment: Thanks Giorgos, noted.